# What hook gets called at the formation of a form? (hook_form_alter called for adjusting a form)

Tags: 7, forms

what hook gets called at the formation of a form.

I'm trying to add some additional mime types to form with id file_entity_add_upload but my hook_form_alter is getting called after these are validated, so attempts to upload them fails.

**Update** - added screenshot to illustrate the problem

[image: screenshot to illustrate the problem]

**Update 2**
the mime types list in file_entity_get_upload_validators function in file_entity.pages.inc dictates what can be uploaded - see this screenshot

[image: uploader]

Specifically, in, file_entity_get_upload_validators, the line that populates the valid mime types with hard-coded values is (my screenshot didn't completely show the line): 
`$validators['file_validate_extensions'] = array(variable_get('file_entity_default_allowed_extensions', 'jpg jpeg gif png txt doc docx xls xlsx pdf ppt pptx pps ppsx odt ods odp'));`

**Update 3**

It would appear that the actual checking of the mime type happens in core module "file", `modules/file/file.js` : `if (!acceptableMatch.test(this.value)) {
        var error = Drupal.t("The selected file %filename cannot be uploaded. Only files with the following extensions are allowed: %extensions.", {`
 I searched the error message shown in following screenshot in the code and file.js was a result - which looks like where the actual validation is taking place.
[image: error when upload]

New error with Andy's answer - maybe it's me will look into it a little later.
[image: error when upload]

Raised as an issue here:
https://www.drupal.org/node/2295671

Comment: Sometimes the implemented hook is correct but it is being called too early or too late because of the relative weights of other modules that have implemented the same hook. In that case, check the weight of the module in the system table and if your implementation is called too early, increase the weight of your module; too late, decrease it.

Comment: Can you post your current code? Are you using the `media` module as well as `file_entity`?

Comment: +1 keithm - thanks for this idea. I couldn't really adjust the module weights but I know what you mean. It might be risky for my particular situation. +1 Andy yes I am using the media module as well as file_entity. The pain seems to be that file.entity determines the valid file extensions but they are hard coded in this module - it's not obvious how to extend to add more mime types. But I found out through debugging that file.entity is validating against an array of mime types as strings which the logic can derives from the form_state variable, if not present here, it uses the hard-coded ones.

Comment: If you edit an individual file bundle (eg. image, document, etc.) via the UI you can define which mimetypes should be associated with it. Have you tried that?

Comment: Thanks I think I have tried that already but this upload is to be within the wysiwyg editor via the media upload, so it appears that the settings used for that are different. I'll review what I've done though but I'm fairly sure I've tried most things in config but they are getting ignore.

Comment: Update: added screenshot to illustrate the problem

Comment: Your screenshot doesn't show the ends of the lines, but looking at [drupalcontrib.org](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!file_entity!file_entity.pages.inc/function/file_entity_get_upload_validators/7) it seems that the valid extensions are passed in via `$options` or are read from the variable `file_entity_default_allowed_extensions`. Have you tried changing that variable? Note that as well as setting up file extensions, the mimetypes per bundle must be correctly configured as well.

Comment: And if you don't want to make the change global, you should be able to modify `#upload_validators['file_validate_extensions']` on the managed file element via a form alter.

Comment: Thanks Andy, but yes I did try to change the $options variable using a hook_form_alter in a custom module but the problem here was that it got called after the mime types had already been 'setup' - in other words the hook_form_alter needs to get called before the file_entity_get_upload_validators function in order for this function to use the updated options values with the new mime types that I added.

Comment: Thanks for the #upload_validators['file_validate_extensions'] suggestion - haven't tried that, relates to pcambra's answer though I fear this may have the same issue if used in hook_form_alter where it happens too late (same problem as I had for modifying $options). Also raised an issue on file_entity about my issue, here: https://www.drupal.org/node/2295671

Comment: I wasn't suggesting using `$options`, but using the variable (if you're happy with a global change). Using `#upload_validators` should work if you want a local change because that's where the return value from `file_entity_get_upload_validators()` goes normally (see [`file_entity_add_upload_step_upload()`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21file_entity%21file_entity.pages.inc/function/file_entity_add_upload_step_upload/7)). Note that a form_alter _always_ happens before FAPI validation.

Comment: Thanks Andy again, though I'm not sure if that kind of validation is used here as it would appear that the actual checking of the mime type happens in core module "file", `modules/file/file.js` : `if (!acceptableMatch.test(this.value)) {
        var error = Drupal.t("The selected file %filename cannot be uploaded. Only files with the following extensions are allowed: %extensions.", {
` - see update to answer - I searched the error message shown and file.js was a result - which looks like where the actual validation is taking place.

Comment: Have you tried modifying either the variable or the property I mentioned? It's not unusual to have both client-side and server-side validation - but they should both be fed by the same data. (IE if you modify either the variable or the property, it should affect both client-side and server-side validation).

Comment: Thanks - What variable again did you mean here - we've talked about a few - do you mean the variable that stores the mime types - as said I have tried to add to this but the key problem is that when I try to use hook_form_alter this does it too late, setup of the form happens well before that. If file_entity_add_upload_step_upload was hookable, I'd be able to add a further validation function, not sure it is...

Comment: If you're happy with a global change, you can change the Drupal variable `file_entity_default_allowed_extensions`. If you want to affect just some forms you can modify `#upload_validators['file_validate_extensions']` on the managed file element. I've just tested both of these approaches with wysiwyg media upload and they worked fine.

Comment: OK thanks Andy. Where did you put your modifying code - in a hook_form_alter? (I would guess)

Comment: I've added an example and some more details in an answer, HTH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`file_entity_add_upload`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21file_entity%21file_entity.pages.inc/function/file_entity_add_upload/7) is a three step form for uploading files when you have fieldable files.

```
function file_entity_add_upload($form, &$form_state, array $options = array()) {
  $step = (isset($form_state['step']) && in_array($form_state['step'], array(1, 2, 3))) ? $form_state['step'] : 1;
  $form['#step'] = $step;
  switch ($step) {
    case 1:
      return file_entity_add_upload_step_upload($form, $form_state, $options);
    case 2:
      return file_entity_add_upload_step_filetype($form, $form_state, $options);
    case 3:
      return file_entity_add_upload_step_fields($form, $form_state, $options);
  }
}
```

1. Upload the file (validates extensions);
2. Choose the file bundle (based on bundle mimetype associations);
3. Fill out fields attached to that bundle.

As the extensions are validated in step 1, examine [`file_entity_add_upload_step_upload()`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21file_entity%21file_entity.pages.inc/function/file_entity_add_upload_step_upload/7). Of particular interest is the actual managed file element.

```
$form['upload'] = array(
  '#type' => 'managed_file', 
  '#title' => t('Upload a new file'), 
  '#upload_location' => file_entity_upload_destination_uri($options), 
  '#upload_validators' => file_entity_get_upload_validators($options), 
  '#progress_indicator' => 'bar', 
  '#required' => TRUE, 
  '#pre_render' => array('file_managed_file_pre_render', 'file_entity_upload_validators_pre_render'), 
  '#default_value' => isset($form_state['storage']['upload']) ? $form_state['storage']['upload'] : NULL,
);
```

The validators are added using a non-standard property `#upload_validators` to set the file validation callbacks *and their arguments*. In the form alter we can completely overwrite `#upload_validators` or just modify it, and that will affect the file's validation as you'd expect. However if you look in [`file_entity_get_upload_validators()`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21file_entity%21file_entity.pages.inc/function/file_entity_get_upload_validators/7):

```
if (!empty($options['file_extensions'])) {
  $validators['file_validate_extensions'] = array($options['file_extensions']);
}
else {
  $validators['file_validate_extensions'] = array(variable_get('file_entity_default_allowed_extensions', 'jpg jpeg gif png txt doc docx xls xlsx pdf ppt pptx pps ppsx odt ods odp'));
}
```

You can see that the variable `file_entity_default_allowed_extensions` is used to specify which extensions to use by default (unless it's overridden by `$options`).

The `managed_file` element itself passes the extensions to JS for client-side validation in [`file_managed_file_process()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!file!file.module/function/file_managed_file_process/7):

```
// Add the extension list to the page as JavaScript settings.
if (isset($element['#upload_validators']['file_validate_extensions'][0])) {
  $extension_list = implode(',', array_filter(explode(' ', $element['#upload_validators']['file_validate_extensions'][0])));
  $element['upload']['#attached']['js'] = array(
    array(
      'type' => 'setting',
      'data' => array('file' => array('elements' => array('#' . $element['#id'] . '-upload' => $extension_list))),
    ),
  );
}
```

As you can see from pcambra's neat illustration, processing happens after form alters are called, so any modifications you make will affect both client-side and server-side validation.

So to make a global change modify the variable `file_entity_default_allowed_extensions`: I'd suggest using drush or a `hook_update_N()`.

To modify a subset of forms you can use a form alter. Here's an example:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter() for file_entity_add_upload.
 *
 * Modifies the allowed extensions.
 */
function MYMODULE_form_file_entity_add_upload_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {

  // Check this is the file selection step.
  if ($form['#step'] != 1) {
    return;
  }

  $form['upload']['#upload_validators']['file_validate_extensions'][0] = 'png bmp';
}
```

Comment: +1 thank you very much for the comprehensive answer - Andy. Nearly there but getting error - http://i.stack.imgur.com/OxImi.png - have to pause on this for today and return tomorrow. Thanks for your help so far. Hoping to accept soon.

Comment: P.S. I've used your code above to add mobi and epub to the mime types. I just created a small <2Mb text file and named it's extension as .mobi

Comment: @therobyouknow grepping on that error it looks like the problem is _The upload directory for the file field could not be created or is not accessible. A newly uploaded file could not be saved in this directory as a consequence, and the upload was canceled_.

Comment: I'll try to do my own digging, save you, when I next get a chance, you've done so much already. OK just got your last comment I'll come back a little later maybe end of today or tomorrow morning. Thanks so much so far, sorry I can't try out the further things re permissions / accessible, right now, will try that later.

Comment: Once again thanks very much for this Andy. I will try to follow up on this today or tomorrow (Friday) and hopefully accept the answer.

Comment: Still will try to look at this, appreciated all the effort. Side tracked atm. Will delete these update comments with the final comment once done.

Comment: @therobyouknow No worries (:

Comment: accepted the answer as I can see, from trying it out, that the MYMODULE_form_file_entity_add_upload_alter enables support for new types. We had some unrelated issues with filesize which, at the time, blocked completion of trying it out, but I feel certain enough that this answer is what is needed.

Answer (score 5):

There's this brilliant image on the [Form API Internal Workflow](https://www.drupal.org/node/165104) in drupal.org, you can see the build process and structure. You've got callbacks such as #process and #after_build that could be useful for your use case.

[image]

Comment: +1 Hey pcambra! thanks for this amazing diagram! I'll study it to see where I can get my code in early enough and hope to accept the answer.