# I am not able to override the form #access setting

Tags: 7, forms, media

I cerated a form alter with the file entity media upload browser. I studied [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/121085/697) of how to alter this form. I then debugged and found that for what I wanted to do, I am in step 4 of the file upload browser as evidenced by the var: `$var['#step'] (Integer) 4`.

Thus my code so far is:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 *
 * Form ID = file_entity_add_upload.
 */
function MYMODULE_form_file_entity_add_upload_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  // Check that this is the fields step.
  if ($form['#step'] == 4) {
  echo 'This is step 4';
  // yep the above prints out.

  // Set access false for the specified field.
  $form['field_usage_restricted']['#access '] = FALSE;

  // Add a dsm after to see what's going on
  dsm($form);
  }
}
```

You'd think this would get rid of the form field, yet, it's still present. See the dsm below:

[image]

I would think that my custom alter `FALSE` setting would override the `TRUE` setting but no such luck, the field is still there.

I can use an `unset($form['field_usage_restricted']);` and that works fine to get rid of the field, but I've learned that `['#access '] = FALSE;` is a better way to go, especially when there's ajax in use such as the case here. I do see in the debug that there's a form after build so I wonder if I need to do that?

I tried this on the off chance it would work but still no joy:

```
if ($form['field_usage_restricted'][LANGUAGE_NONE]['#after_build'][0]) {
  // Set access false for the specified field.
  $form['field_usage_restricted']['#access '] = FALSE;
}
```

(Note, my field, `field_usage_restricted` is not a required field.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$form['field_usage_restricted']['#access ']` the `#access` key has a space in it. Only reason I can think of you would get two items in the array like that. Remove that space, and dump the item out again. It should be overwritten and have `FALSE` for a value.

Comment: Oh gosh, that's what happens when you stare at something too long. Thank you!